# Convert wide to long structure in SQL Server without aggregation on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
zip      y       z
---------------------
99555   1.1      1.1
99556   1.1      0.8
```

I am trying to get the output into a long structure with giving y an alias of Const. and z an alias of NonConst.

```
zip      Value          Type
---------------------------------
99555     1.1           Const.
99555     1.1           NonConst.
99556     1.1           Const.
99556     .8            NonConst.
```

I tried `case when end` statements, but it wasn't working. Is there some other way. I am using SQL Server.

SOLUTION:

```
CREATE table #yourtable
(
     [zip] int,  
     [y] float, 
     [z] float
)

INSERT INTO #yourtable ([zip], [y], [z])
VALUES (99555, 1.1, 1.1),
       (99556, 1.1, .8)

SELECT 
    t.zip, tt.value, tt.z
FROM
    #yourtable t 
CROSS APPLY
    (VALUES ('Const.', y), ('NonConst.', z)) tt(Value, z);
```

Comment: I don't think SQL Server 2010 exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `apply` :

```
select t.zip, tt.value, tt.z as Type
from table t cross apply
     ( values ('Const.', y), ('NonConst.', z) 
     ) tt(Value, z);
```